# Trigger to show comma-separated products in the text area custom field whenever the order line item is changed

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Trigger to show comma-separated products in the below custom field whenever the order line item is added/updated/deleted. Custom field on Order - xyz(textArea)

I am completely new to development and have been trying a lot to write but can't move forward really. Not sure whether to write on Order Object or which one. Also, I am getting a error 1) Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, Order) from the type Map<Id,OrderItem> .

Below is the code which I wrote:-

```java
trigger trigger_name on OrderItem (after insert, after update) {

    if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete) {
        Map<Id,OrderItem> items = new Map<Id,OrderItem>([Select id, Product2Id from OrderItem]);
  
        for (Order ord: trigger.new) {            
            if (ord.OrdersProduct__c != null) {
                items.put(ord.OrdersProduct__c, ord);  
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community! You are on the right track, your trigger should be on the `OrderItem` object. One thing that I noticed is missing is the `after delete` event in the trigger definition.

A trigger like the one below should do the trick:

```java
trigger OrderItemTrigger on OrderItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    // Get the modified OrderItems depending on the operation
    List<OrderItem> modifiedOrderItems;

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        modifiedOrderItems = Trigger.new;
    }
    else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        modifiedOrderItems = Trigger.old;
    }

    // Use the modified OrderItems to get the IDs of their parent Orders
    Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (OrderItem oi : modifiedOrderItems) {
        orderIds.add(oi.OrderId);
    }

    // Retrieve all OrderItems related to the modified Orders
    List<OrderItem> orderItems = [
        SELECT Id, OrderId, Product2.Name
        FROM OrderItem
        WHERE OrderId IN :orderIds
    ];

    // Update text area field (Order_Products__c) on Orders
    Map<Id, Order> orderMap = new Map<Id, Order>();

    for (OrderItem oi : orderItems) {
        Id parentOrderId = oi.OrderId;

        if (!orderMap.containsKey(parentOrderId)) {
            orderMap.put(parentOrderId, new Order(Id = parentOrderId));
        }

        Order parentOrder = orderMap.get(parentOrderId);
        parentOrder.Order_Products__c += oi.Product2.Name + '\n';
    }

    if (!orderMap.isEmpty()) {
        List<Order> parentOrders = orderMap.values();
        update parentOrders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bit naive, doesn't work on update that changes Order header (you'd then need to update old & new order), delete, undelete (restore from recycle bin). It's just to give you an idea.

This should get you started. No promises it'll compile, written in notepad.

```
// Collect Ids of all order headers we must check
Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
    for(OrderItem oi : trigger.new){
        orderIds.add(oi.OrderId);
    }
}
// Query them and all their line items in one go.
List<Order> orders = [SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Product2Id, Quantity, ListPrice 
    FROM OrderItems
    ORDER BY OrderItemNumber)
    FROM Order
    WHERE Id IN :orderIds];

// actual "rollup"
for(Order o : orders){
    if(o.OrderItems.isEmpty()){
        o.OrdersProduct__c = null;
    } else {
        List<String> rows = new List<String>();
        for(OrderItem oi : o.OrderItems){
            rows.add(String.join(new List<String>{
                String.valueOf(oi.Product2Id),
                String.valueOf(oi.Quantity),
                String.valueOf(ListPrice)
            }, ';'));
        }
        o.OrdersProduct__c = String.join(rows, '\n');
    }
}
update orders;
```